# When is Inn(G) abelian or cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

I proved Inn(G) cyclic implies G abelian.

and if G finite group, then Aut(G) cyclic iff G cyclic and order G is either 1,2, 4 or $p^k$ or 2$p^k$.

Is there chacterisation for(given G is finite group):

**Question 1:** When Inn(G) is cyclic?

**Question 2:** When Inn(G) is abelian?

**Question 3:** When Aut(G) is abelian?

Comment: Question 1: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403114/inng-cannot-be-nontrivial-cyclic-group). Question 2: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709658/g-a-non-abelian-group-of-order-p3-show-that-inng-is-abelian). Question 3: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296935/autg-is-abelian).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks but for question 2 atleast you only mentioned sufficinet condition for Inn(G) abelian. Is there a necessary condition also

Comment: $\textrm{Inn}(G)$ is abelian iff $G/Z(G)$ is abelian iff $G$ is at most $2$-step nilpotent.

Comment: sorry not familiar with term 2-step nilpotent. Can you explain or give soem reference @KeithKearnes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group